# Время конкретного пользователя в Java

Tags: java, spring, datetime

В коде имеется сервис, который разрешает/отклоняет HTTP запрос в зависимости от времени (до 11:00 разрешено, после - запрещено).
На текущий момент реализовано крайне просто:

```
public Vote vote(Restaurant restaurant, User user) {
    Vote voteFromRepo = voteRepository.findByUserIdAndDate(user.getId(), LocalDate.now());
    if (voteFromRepo != null && LocalTime.now().isAfter(LocalTime.of(11, 0))) {
        throw new VoteDenyException();
    }
    return voteRepository.save(new Vote(restaurant, user));
}
```

Как привязать проверку времени к часовому поясу пользователя, а не к системному времени?

Answer (score 2):

Используйте LocalDateTime, там есть возможность задать TimeZone. В базе храните все даты в формате UTC, когда даты показываются пользователям отображаете им даты, приводя к их часовому поясу. В вашем случае в запросе отправляйте текущие дату,время и часовой пояс клиента.

Посмотреть как на клиенте получить дату и зону можно здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091372/getting-the-clients-timezone-offset-in-javascript

Comment: а как его считать у клиента? предложить выбрать в момент регистрации?

Comment: Можно посмотреть здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10211145/getting-current-date-and-time-in-javascript

Comment: и здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091372/getting-the-clients-timezone-offset-in-javascript